# Installing gradle 4.8.1 have broken TeamCity 9 installation

Tags: gradle, installation, teamcity, teamcity-9.0, connection-refused

For few days ago I installed gradle on our buildserver which our TeamCity server is running on too. 
Today I noticed that TeamCity is not working anymore and I am getting this error on connection page:

```
This site can’t be reached
temamcity-server refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

After digging into logs I found just one warningabout connection inside teamcity-agent.logs and nothing inside teamcity-server.logs. The log messag is this:

```
[2018-06-21 20:27:51,440]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Failed to resolve server communication protocol. Will try all protocols: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (enable debug to see stacktrace)
```

The warning is repeating several times but the first time it appears in the log is exactly after installation of Gradle.
I restarted TeamCity server but nothing has changed. I checked ports but I couldn't find any conflict.
Anybody has some idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Try connecting to the HTTP port of TeamCity server from the TeamCity server machine and if that fails, check logs in the TeamCity server's logs directory.

Comment: Thanks @Yaegor for your answer. How do you mean I should try connectin to Http port on teamcity machine?